# images shows blank when on mozilla browser

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

for some reason my images only shows as white when I use Mozilla, but appears fine on different browsers, I have tried -moz tho cannot seem to get this to work. I know its a basic change but I for some reason I can't find the fix. Hope someone can help.

Just a sidenote it shows blank when page load, but when I hover on the image it works perfectly.

```css
/*Projects Page CSS*/

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card-title {
  color: white !important;
}

.card-modal-header {
  color: #F15632 !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black !important;
}

.card-title:hover {
  color: #F15632 !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black !important;
}

.card-body {
  background-color: #363636;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #F15632;
  border-top: hidden;
}

.card-img-top {
  border: 1px solid #F15632;
  border-bottom: hidden;
}

.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F15632;
  border-top: 1px solid #F15632;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -moz-transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(0, 1);
}

.overlay-header-color {
  color: #F15632 !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black !important;
}

.overlay-header-color-link {
  color: #F15632 !important;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px black !important;
}

.overlay-header-color-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter');
  filter: brightness(0.6);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.6);
  -moz-filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -moz-transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect a,
.hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -moz-transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a,
.hovereffect:hover p,
.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">


  <br/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="kitchen" class="card">
        <a href="#modal-project1" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/kitchen-black-white-2.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project1" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Kitchen Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project1" data-toggle="modal">Kitchen Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="bar" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project2" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/bar-3.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project2" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Bar Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project2" data-toggle="modal">Bar Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="bathroom" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project3" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/bathroom-black-2.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project3" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Bathroom Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project3" data-toggle="modal">Bathroom Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="closet" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project4" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/closet-black-1.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project4" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Build in Closet Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project4" data-toggle="modal">Build in Closet Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="koi-pond" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project5" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/koipond-bridge-2.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project5" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Koi Pond Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project5" data-toggle="modal">Koi Pond Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="painting" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project6" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/painting-house-modern-4.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project6" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Painting Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project6" data-toggle="modal">Painting Projects</a>
          </h4>
          <!--<p class="text-muted card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur eum quasi sapiente nesciunt? Voluptatibus sit, repellat sequi itaque deserunt, dolores in, nesciunt, illum tempora ex quae? Nihil, dolorem!</p>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="patio" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project7" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/patio-pizza-7.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project7" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Patio Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project7" data-toggle="modal">Patio Projects</a>
          </h4>
          <!--<p class="text-muted card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur eum quasi sapiente nesciunt? Voluptatibus sit, repellat sequi itaque deserunt, dolores in, nesciunt, illum tempora ex quae? Nihil, dolorem!</p>-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="renovation" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project8" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/patio-open-plan-4.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project8" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Renovation Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project8" data-toggle="modal">Renovation Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
      <div id="add-renovation" class="card ">
        <a href="#modal-project9" data-toggle="modal">
          <div class="hovereffect">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="projects-main/eldoradopark-13.jpg" alt="">
            <a href="#modal-project9" data-toggle="modal">
              <div class="overlay">
                <h2 class="overlay-header-color">Additional Renovation Projects</h2>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">
            <a class="card-title" href="#modal-project9" data-toggle="modal">Additional Renovation Projects</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



</div>
```

[image: Basically this is the issue I have, blank images until I hover over them]

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: a hard refresh might help `ctrl+F5`

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you are having this problem locally, did you try to another person computer remotely :

Check the permissions for the domain in the current tab in Tools > Page Info > Permissions
Check that images are enabled: Tools > Options > Content: [X] Load images automatically
Check the exceptions in Tools > Options > Content: Load Images > Exceptions
Check the "Tools > Page Info > Media" tab for blocked images (scroll through all the images with the cursor Down key).

This mozilla support link can [help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/839653)

Comment: don't think it is the settings. The site is already live, saw this issue on the clients laptop. and have the same issue on my Mozilla, when the site is live or even local.

Comment: Thinking it could be a css change that I need to make